# Django Object Permission "django-guardian" chnage Admin object permission UI

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-guardian, django-3.0

I want to  change some Admin UI in Object Permission(Django-guardian).

I only want to Given Group Permission to the respective Obj and search the group name replace by   Show  All Group  and select the Group.

How to customize the Admin Panel for Object Permission.